# oracle interpreting real time sql monitor report

Tags: sql, oracle, monitoring

I am trying to interpret the output of a html based SQL monitoring report. Unable to understand the reason for arrows in certain steps of the execution plan. Can someone help me understand the purpose?

```
|    63 |             VIEW                                         
| -> 64 |              HASH UNIQUE                                
| -> 65 |               VIEW                                      
| -> 66 |                JOIN FILTER USE                          
| -> 67 |                 UNION-ALL                               
|    68 |                  PARTITION COMBINED ITERATOR            
|    69 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCH
|    70 |                    SORT CLUSTER BY ROWID                
|    71 |                     INDEX SKIP SCAN                     
| -> 72 |                  PARTITION COMBINED ITERATOR
```

Comment: The arrows are there to tell you the steps that are currently being performed.

Comment: @gsalem -  Do you mean even a non-parallel session will execute multiple operations. Can you please explain as this was executed without parallelism.

Comment: Take the example of a hash join: it reads the first table, builds a hash array, then starts reading the second table, and for each row, test if it joins, so you get an arrow on the scan of the second table, as well as on the hash join step. It is not doing this in multiple threads, but a single thread doing the scan, then the hash, then the scan again, then hash, ....